# How to run nodejs within a Linux C# Azure function?

Tags: c#, node.js, azure-functions

I have some code that works locally on my Windows machine where I have Node installed on it.

When I run the code on Azure I get:

> An error occurred trying to start process 'node' with working
> directory '/home/site/wwwroot'. No such file or directory

I have not specified a working directory and it works locally so I'm thinking maybe node is not installed for C# Azure functions?

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "node",
    Arguments = $"my-file.js",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};

using (Process process = new Process { StartInfo = start })
{
    process.Start();
    var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
//locally I can debug here and see valid output. The deployed code on Azure errors on the using statement
}
```

Is it even possible to try and call Nodejs from a C# Azure function with the way I am trying to do it?

Comment: How are you hosting the function? Isolated worker model and in-process model and is it on a consumption plan or attached to an app service plan? These may affect what you have access to.

Another option would be to use a nodejs function rather than C#

Comment: Currently on an isolated model on a consumption plan but happy to change to fit my scenario. Basically I want to do some C# logic that passes some data to Nodejs then pass that back to C#. I guess my C# Azure function could call a Nodejs Azure function but hoping for a cleaner way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***You can try using the below code to call your js file in c# function:-***

In order for below code to work make sure the node file exist in the Azure Functions core tools folder.

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public static class MyFunction
{
    [FunctionName("CallNodeJSFunction")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        // Specify the name of your Node.js file
        string nodeJsFileName = "my-file.js";

        // Get the base directory of the current assembly (your function app)
        string baseDirectory = System.AppContext.BaseDirectory;

        // Construct the full path to the Node.js file
        string nodeJsFilePath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, nodeJsFileName);

        Process nodeProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "node",
                Arguments = nodeJsFilePath,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true, // Redirect standard error
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
            }
        };

        nodeProcess.Start();
        string output = await nodeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
        string errorOutput = await nodeProcess.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync(); // Read error output
        nodeProcess.WaitForExit();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorOutput))
        {
            log.LogError($"Node.js script encountered an error: {errorOutput}");
        }

        return new OkObjectResult(output);
    }
}
```

If you want to call NodeJS Function in c# one way is ti deploy a NodeJs Function and call its URL in the C# function like below:-

[image]

I am calling this **`URL`** in my **`C# function`** like below:-

**My HttpTrigger C# code:-**

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static class MyHttpTriggerFunction
{
    [FunctionName("CallExternalUrl")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        // Create an instance of HttpClient
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            string targetUrl = "https://nodejsfunc76.azurewebsites.net/api/httpTrigger1";

            
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(targetUrl);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return new OkObjectResult(responseBody);
            }
            else
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult($"Failed to call the URL: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]